# Form element added using jQuery is not sent on POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, zend-form

I have a zend_form where I'm allowing the user to add form elements dynamically.
Elements are added dynamically using jQuery : something like...

```
$(function(){
  $('#more_answers').click(function(){
    var elemNum = $('.dummy-element').size();

    $("<dd class='dummy-element' id='dummyanswer_"+elemNum+"-element'><input type='text' value='' id='dummyanswer_"+elemNum+"' name='dummyanswer_"+elemNum+"'></dd>").insertBefore('#more_answers-element');

    return false;
  });
});
```

The element is added correctly-within the  tags.
When I submit,the element added is not submitted.
I checked in the  in the Net view in firebug and the variable is indeed not passed at all.

What could the issue be?
Would it have anything to do with zend_form specifically? I have added elements in the past to Zend_Forms using raw JavaScript and it was working just fine.

Any thoughts?

Thanks, I really appreciate it!

More markup for form elements as requested:

```
<dd class="dummy-element" id="dummyanswer_2-element">
  <input type="text" value="" id="dummyanswer_2" name="dummyanswer_2">
</dd> <!-- this element was NOT added using jquery -->
<dd id="dummyanswer_3-element" class="dummy-element">
  <input type="text" name="dummyanswer_3" id="dummyanswer_3" value="">
</dd> <!-- this element was added using jquery -->
<dd id="more_answers-element">
  <input width="170px" height="30px" type="image" style="" class="addDummyAnswer" src="/images/add_more_dummy_answers_button_370X60px.png" id="more_answers" name="more_answers">
</dd>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup for the `#more_answers-element` and surrounding elements?

Comment: yes i'm adding it to the post

Comment: Are you sure that the place you're adding the `<input>` elements is really *inside* the `<form>` tag?

Comment: yes it is. at least that is what i see when I do a view source in firefox

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem once. If the form is inside a table, the element added (the input) will be a child of the table cell, not a child of the Form and will not be "linked" to the form as one of the form fields, even if the table tags are inside the form tags.

If you add the input field directly as a child of the form DOM node, then it will be "linked" to the form as one of its fields and should be submitted normally.

The big question is, can one somehow "link" an added input element to a form, when that element is added dynamically to the DOM as a child of a non-form node? I was never able to find a solution.

I had this problem when working on a Firefox extension, so this behavior was observed on Firefox. Not sure how other browsers handle the situation. Maybe you are experiencing something similar.

Comment: Hi,
Since its a zend form, everything is within fieldsets by default,
I also have <div>'s within the form, no tables anywhere though.
Somehow it doesnot seem logical for the <form> to not recognize an element that is within the  form tags

Comment: I think the problem was not particularly related to the table, but to the fact that there were nodes between the form itself and the added input field. At least, in my case.

Comment: in my case the problem was i was rendering the form in a table without tr/td tags

Comment: "If the form is inside a table, ...." I totally forgot about that... I wasted 30min on this, thanks +1 (no relation with Zend)

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved - I was looking at the source in firefox and things were indeed rendered properly.
However, I opened the same thing in web developer and the form tag was hidden.
it looked something like this:

```
             <dl class = "zend_form">
                    <!---- all the elements -->
             </dl>
          <table>
               <form....></form> <!-- everything hidden -->   
         </table>
```

i deleted the table tag and it formatted fine.
in this case, i believe it was because I did not have a < tr > within the table tag, so the < dl > was rendered outside the table and the form was rendered within the table.
However, that still begs the question - why does it show up correctly in 'View Source'?

Answer (score 0):

I got here when search StackOverflow for a similar case, which was coded maybe too long ago. So the problem is probably because the mal-formed HTML, somebody put the <form> tag with in <table> tag, which I can't get dynamically added DOM elements. Once I reverse it, it seems working fine. So just add my 2 cents here.

Comment: What is the logic of 2 cents?